# Toilet Fill Tube Connection

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

On my toilets, both fill tubes are connected to the OUTSIDE of the overflow tubes, so the stream of water is going directly to the tank.

I went ahead and directed the stream to now go into the overflow tube.

Will this help the performance of the toilets now?

Comment: You have **two** fill tubes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's how it's supposed to be.

You have water coming out by the tube which has the on/off mechanism and a small flexible pipe that is expected to send water inside the overflow tube to refill the bowl. Without that, the bowl is not likely to refill much, actually.

I uploaded a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWndFZX3wxc) to show it in action.

[image]

Comment: ...I think you mean bowl, not tank. Or pan, not cistern for our cross-ponders.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Correct! I made a quick edit. Thank you.